# addDays and addMonths to a date methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, calendar

I am using Netbeans 8. I am still in the beginner courses for computer science.
I am trying to write two methods which are addDays and addMonths.
Here are the methods

```
public void addMonths(int n) {
    month += n;
    if (month >= 13) {
      month = 0 + n - 1;
    }
}
public void addDays(int n) {
    day += n;
    if (day >= 32) {
      day = 0 + n ;
    }
}
```

I know they are wrong. Can someone help me fix them ? Please keep it simple and not use advanced coding.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not allowed to use `Date` or `Calendar` or Joda?

Comment: you may want to check the `Calendar` class, read the java, you will find the way.

Comment: @Compass I assume that this is homework and the requirements will restrict library usage.

Comment: @deyur I implied not only as instances, but also as source code for explaining the logic.

Comment: FYI: [a] Defining what it means to add a month is tricky. Is it the same numbered day-of-month? Is so, what about adding one month to January 31 where there is no 29, 30, or 31 in February? [b] [Leap Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) is another issue to handle. [c] While I understand this is homework, know that in the real world we rely on existing libraries to handle this kind of troublesome chore. In Java, the best libraries are [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and the java.time package bundled with Java 8 (and inspired by Joda-Time).

Answer (score 3):

Your case it should be something like this a class defined for calculation.This is a basic class. with a constructor and 3 add methods.

Please note this does not contain any math to generate correct date e.g. feb has 28 days and in leap year has 29.This code consider all months to be 31 days long.

```
public class MyDate {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public MyDate(int d,int m,int y){
        day=d;
        month=m;
        year=y;
    }

    public void addMonths(int n) {
        if(n>12){ // Checks if we trying to add more that 12 we add so many years
            addYears(n%12);
            n-= 12*(n%12);
        }
        month += n;
        if(month>=13){
            addYears(1);
            month-=12;
        }
    }
    public void addDays(int n) {
        if(n>31){
            addMonths(n%31);
            n-=31*(n%31);
        }
        day += n;
        if(day>=32) {
            day-=31;
            addMonths(1);
        }
    }
    public void addYears(int n) {
        year += n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
public void addMonths(int n) {
    month += n;
    numYear = month/12;
    month = (month % 12) + 1;
    addYears(numYear);
}

public void addDays(int n) {    
    day += n;
    numMonths = day/31;
    day = (day % 31) + 1;
    addMonths(numMonths);
}
```